# call copy constructor from assignment operator function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a class with a point to dynamically allocated array, so I created copy constructor and assignment operator function. Since copy constructor and assignment operator function do the same work, I call copy constructor from the assignment operator function but get `"error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter"`. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

```
// default constructor
FeatureValue::FeatureValue()
{
    m_value = NULL;
}

// copy constructor 
FeatureValue::FeatureValue(const FeatureValue& other)
{
    m_size = other.m_size;  
    delete[] m_value;
    m_value = new uint8_t[m_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {
        m_value[i] = other.m_value[i];
    }
}

// assignment operator function
FeatureValue& FeatureValue::operator=(const FeatureValue& other)
{
    FeatureValue(other); // error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The offending line isn't what you think it is. It actually declares a variable `other` of type `FeatureValue`. This is because constructors to not have names and cannot be called directly.

You can safely invoke the copy assignment operator from the constructor as long as the operator is not declared virtual.

```
FeatureValue::FeatureValue(const FeatureValue& other)
    : m_value(nullptr), m_size(0)
{
    *this = other;
}

// assignment operator function
FeatureValue& FeatureValue::operator=(const FeatureValue& other)
{
    if(this != &other)
    {
        // copy data first. Use std::unique_ptr if possible
        // avoids destroying our data if an exception occurs
        uint8_t* value = new uint8_t[other.m_size];
        int size = other.m_size;  

        for (int i = 0; i < other.m_size; i++)
        {
            value[i] = other.m_value[i];
        }

        // Assign values
        delete[] m_value;
        m_value = value;
        m_size = size;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This will works just dandy or you can use the typical guidelines for the copy & swap idiom suggested in [Vaughn Cato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17480407/845568)

Comment: why don't just `m_value[i] = other.m_value[i]` instead of using intermediate value, e.g. `value[i] = other.m_value[i]`?

Answer (score 14):

You can't directly call a constructor like you would any other method.  What you are doing is actually declaring a variable called `other` of type `FeatureValue`.

Take a look at the copy-and-swap idiom for a good way to avoid duplication between the assignment operator and the copy constructor: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/951890)

Even better, use a `std::vector` instead of `new` and `delete`.  Then you don't need to write your own copy constructor or assignment operator.

Comment: It's Bjoink all over again!

Comment: Its uncanny how you guys both answered the same thing at the same time.

Comment: @Borgleader what you may find even more odd is I've know about Vaughn for well over about 25 years. He just didn't know about me ;)

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to call copy constructor from the assignment operator function then?

Comment: @zwx: No -- you could put the common code into a third function that both the constructor and the assignment operator call though.

Comment: @zwx: Note that your copy constructor has a problem though, you are calling `delete[] m_value`, when `m_value` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @zwx: Take a look at the copy-and-swap idiom for a good way to avoid duplication between the assignment operator and the copy constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/951890

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: viva la CoCo!

Comment: @VaughnCato. I am doing this because if the copy constructor is called after is object is initialized, the original `m_value` array need to be deleted before assigning new values.

Comment: @zwx: Are you saying that `m_value` is a member of a base class?  Otherwise, there is no way it would already have been initialized.

Comment: @VaughnCato: it's a member of `FeatureValue` class. `FeatureValue` class also has another constructor which I didn't list.

Comment: Doh! The obvious `std::vector`. I'll turn in my cape and tights now.

Comment: @zwx: m_value must be a pointer.  You have no constructor initializer list, so m_value will be uninitialized at the beginning of the body of your constructor.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer - don't do it.

Details:

```
// copy constructor 
FeatureValue::FeatureValue(const FeatureValue& other)
{
    m_size = other.m_size;  
    delete[] m_value;      // m_value NOT INITIALISED - DON'T DELETE HERE!
    m_value = new uint8_t[m_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {
        m_value[i] = other.m_value[i];
    }
}

// assignment operator function
FeatureValue& FeatureValue::operator=(const FeatureValue& other)
{
    FeatureValue(other); // error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter
    return *this;
}
```

Notes:

- When the copy constructor is called, it's constructing the new object with reference to the object being copied, but the default constructor does not run before the copy constructor.  This means `m_value` has an indeterminate value when the copy constructor starts running - you can assign to it, but to read from it is undefined behaviour, and to `delete[]` it considerably worse (if anything can be worse than UD! ;-)).  So, just leave out that `delete[]` line.

Next, if `operator=` tries to leverage the functionality from the copy constructor, it has to first release any existing data `m_value` is pointing at or it will be leaked.  Most people try to do that as follows (**which is broken**) - I think this is what you were trying for:

```
FeatureValue& FeatureValue::operator=(const FeatureValue& other)
{
    // WARNING - this code's not exception safe...!
    ~FeatureValue();  // call own destructor
    new (this) FeatureValue(other); // reconstruct object
    return *this;
}
```

The problem with this is that if the creation of FeatureValue fails (e.g. because `new` can't get the memory it wants), then the `FeatureValue` object is left with an invalid state (e.g. `m_value` might be pointing off into space).  Later when the destructor runs and does a `delete[] m_value`, you have undefined behaviour (your program will probably crash).

You really should approach this more systematically... either writing it out step by step, or perhaps implementing a guaranteed non-throwing `swap()` method (easy to do... just `std::swap()` `m_size` and `m_value`, and using it ala:

```
FeatureValue& FeatureValue::operator=(FeatureValue other)
{
    swap(other);
    return *this;
}
```

That's easy and clean, but it has a couple minor performance/efficiency issues:

- keeping any existing `m_value` array around longer than necessary, increasing peak memory usage... you could call `clear()`.  In practice, most non-trivial programs wouldn't care about this unless the data structure in question was holding huge amounts of data (e.g. hundreds of megabytes or gigabytes for a PC app).
- not even trying to reuse the existing `m_value` memory - instead always doing another `new` for `other` (that can lead to reduced memory usage but isn't always worthwhile).

Ultimately, the reasons there can be distinct copy constructor and `operator=` - rather than having the compiler automatically create one from the other - is that optimally efficient implementations can't - in general - leverage each other in the way you'd hoped.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `FeatureValue(other);` actually invokes the copy constructor to create a new Featurevalue object,which has nothing to do with `*this`.